# SQL Server CE Update table from another table

Tags: sql-server-ce

Having trouble trying to adjust what is usually a simple update from one table to another:

```
UPDATE t2 
SET Country_FK = t1.Country_ID 
FROM dbo.CountryCity t2
INNER JOIN dbo.Country t1 ON t2.country = t1.ISO
```

Doing a bit of research, SQL Server CE does not like the `FROM` clause in a join.

I just can't seem to get the syntax right to work on SQL Server CE.

Any suggestion are more than welcome.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the SQL CE [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174122.aspx), `FROM` clauses are not supported in `UPDATE`. Nor can you do `UPDATE CountryCity SET Country_FK = (SELECT Country_ID FROM Country...` because `SET` only accepts a scalar and `SELECT` returns a selection.

You will have to assign the first or only value from

```
SELECT Country_ID FROM Country c
INNER JOIN CountryCity cc ON cc.country = c.ISO
WHERE you need something here to specify one country instead of every country that has any matching ISO
```

to `CountryCity.Country_FK WHERE country = same country you specified above`

This has to be done in whatever script or application is calling your SQL command, it cannot be done inside SQL CE.

Comment: Well I agree. I sounds like I am going to have to write some code to fill a datatable from CountryCity table, loop through it, find it's match from Country table, get it's value, dynamically create the update script for that one record and update. Talk about inefficient.

Comment: You will need a dataset and to loop through anything only if you expect your first query to return multiple countries, and you want to assign different countries to different `CountryCity` rows. If that is the case, you would have to use a loop or cursor (which is a loop internally) in any version of SQL.